# Converting rows to desired JSON format in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, json

Trying to convert the data in required JSON but wasn't successful, any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

SQL Server version: 2019

Test script:

```
drop table if exists t1
go
create table t1(id int, key int, value varchar(10))
go
insert into t1 values (100, 1, 'value11')
insert into t1 values (100, 2, 'value12')
insert into t1 values (100, 3, 'value13')
insert into t1 values (100, 4, 'value14')
go
insert into t1 values (200, 1, 'value21')
insert into t1 values (200, 2, 'value22')
insert into t1 values (200, 3, 'value23')
insert into t1 values (200, 4, 'value24')
go
select  
    t.id, t.key, t.value
from t1 as t
for json path,  WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Output:

```
{"id":100,"key":1,"value":"value11"},
{"id":100,"key":2,"value":"value12"},
{"id":100,"key":3,"value":"value13"},
{"id":100,"key":4,"value":"value14"},
{"id":200,"key":1,"value":"value21"},
{"id":200,"key":2,"value":"value22"},
{"id":200,"key":3,"value":"value23"},
{"id":200,"key":4,"value":"value24"}
```

Desired output:

```
100, {"1":"value11","2":"value12","3":"value13","4":"value14"}

200, {"1":"value21","2":"value22","3":"value23","4":"value24"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shape doesn't come easy to FOR JSON to transform data (column values) into metadata (json keys).  But it's easy to do with string_agg, eg:

```
select t.id, 
    '{' + STRING_AGG(concat(quotename([key],'"'),':',quotename(value,'"')),',') within group( order by value ) + '}' value
from t1 as t
group by id 
order by id
```